# How to use GSON with 5 day forecast openweathermap app correctly

Tags: android, json, api, gson, openweathermap

I'm trying to put together a weather app. I'm using the 5 day forecast from openweathermap api and I'm wondering if I'm parsing and connecting the api correctly since it has more data then the current weather api. Can anyone let me know if my code is correct? Here is part of my code.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weather_app, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

    new GetWeatherAync().execute(getActivity());
    return view;


}
  private class GetWeatherAync extends AsyncTask<Context, Void,      
List<ForecastWeatherList>> {
    private String TAG = GetWeatherAync.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ForecastWeatherList> doInBackground(Context...params) {
        mContext = params[0];
        return getWeatherFromServer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<ForecastWeatherList> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "populate UI recycler view with gson converted data");

            RecyclerViewAdapter weatherRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(result, mContext);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(weatherRecyclerViewAdapter);
        }

    }
}

public List<ForecastWeatherList> getWeatherFromServer(){
    String serviceUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + searchView + api_key;
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(serviceUrl);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(4000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(4000);
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        //pass buffered reader to convert json to javaobject using gson
        return convertJsonToObject(bufferedReader);

    }catch (Exception e){

    }

    return null;
}

public List<ForecastWeatherList> convertJsonToObject(BufferedReader bufferedReader){
    final Gson gson = new Gson();

    //pass root element type to fromJson method along with input stream

    ForecastWeatherListWrapper weatherWrapper = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader,ForecastWeatherListWrapper.class);

    List<ForecastWeatherList> weatherlst = weatherWrapper.getforecastWeatherLists();

    return weatherlst;
}
```

Here is my GSON code. There are classes for Clouds, Main, Rain, Sys, Weather and Wind.

```
public class ForecastWeatherList {
@SerializedName("dt")
@Expose
private Integer dt;
@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private Main main;
@SerializedName("weather")
@Expose
private Weather weather = null;
@SerializedName("clouds")
@Expose
private Clouds clouds;
@SerializedName("wind")
@Expose
private Wind wind;
@SerializedName("rain")
@Expose
private Rain rain;
@SerializedName("sys")
@Expose
private Sys sys;
@SerializedName("dt_txt")
@Expose
private String dtTxt;

public Integer getDt() {
    return dt;
}

public void setDt(Integer dt) {
    this.dt = dt;
}

public Main getMain() {
    return main;
}

public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

public Weather getWeather() {
    return (Weather) weather;
}

public void setWeather(Weather weather) {
    this.weather = weather;
}

public Clouds getClouds() {
    return clouds;
}

public void setClouds(Clouds clouds) {
    this.clouds = clouds;
}

public Wind getWind() {
    return wind;
}

public void setWind(Wind wind) {
    this.wind = wind;
}

public Rain getRain() {
    return rain;
}

public void setRain(Rain rain) {
    this.rain = rain;
}

public Sys getSys() {
    return sys;
}

public void setSys(Sys sys) {
    this.sys = sys;
}

public String getDtTxt() {
    return dtTxt;
}

public void setDtTxt(String dtTxt) {
    this.dtTxt = dtTxt;
}
```

}

Here is the wrapper I am using.

```
  public class ForecastWeatherListWrapper {

  private List<ForecastWeatherList> forecastWeatherLists;

public List<ForecastWeatherList> getforecastWeatherLists() {
    return forecastWeatherLists;
}

public void setforecastWeatherLists(List<ForecastWeatherList> forecastWeatherItems){

    this.forecastWeatherLists = forecastWeatherItems;
}
```

}

This is the first time I'm using GSON to parse JSON data so my question is whether I'm using it correctly to parse my JSON data given there are other classes such as Main, Clouds, etc and whether I'm connecting to the internet with the api correctly. Thanks.

Here is my main class:

```
public class Main {

@SerializedName("temp")
@Expose
private Double temp;
@SerializedName("temp_min")
@Expose
private Double tempMin;
@SerializedName("temp_max")
@Expose
private Double tempMax;
@SerializedName("pressure")
@Expose
private Double pressure;
@SerializedName("sea_level")
@Expose
private Double seaLevel;
@SerializedName("grnd_level")
@Expose
private Double grndLevel;
@SerializedName("humidity")
@Expose
private Integer humidity;
@SerializedName("temp_kf")
@Expose
private Integer tempKf;

public Double getTemp() {
    return temp;
}

    public void setTemp(Double temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public Double getTempMin() {
        return tempMin;
    }

    public void setTempMin(Double tempMin) {
        this.tempMin = tempMin;
    }

    public Double getTempMax() {
        return tempMax;
    }

    public void setTempMax(Double tempMax) {
        this.tempMax = tempMax;
    }

public Double getPressure() {
    return pressure;
}

public void setPressure(Double pressure) {
    this.pressure = pressure;
}

public Double getSeaLevel() {
    return seaLevel;
}

public void setSeaLevel(Double seaLevel) {
    this.seaLevel = seaLevel;
}

public Double getGrndLevel() {
    return grndLevel;
}

public void setGrndLevel(Double grndLevel) {
    this.grndLevel = grndLevel;
}

public Integer getHumidity() {
    return humidity;
}

public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
    this.humidity = humidity;
}

public Integer getTempKf() {
    return tempKf;
}

public void setTempKf(Integer tempKf) {
    this.tempKf = tempKf;
}

}
```

Here is my raw string data (I think).

```
 "cod":"200",
"message":0.0074,
  "cnt":39,
"list":[
  {
     "dt":1534215600,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.24,
        "temp_min":292.346,
        "temp_max":293.24,
        "pressure":1021.77,
        "sea_level":1028.21,
        "grnd_level":1021.77,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.89
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":20
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.51,
        "deg":275.001
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":0.0050000000000008
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 03:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534226400,
     "main":{
        "temp":292.3,
        "temp_min":291.706,
        "temp_max":292.3,
        "pressure":1020.99,
        "sea_level":1027.42,
        "grnd_level":1020.99,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.6
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.52,
        "deg":294.505
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 06:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534237200,
     "main":{
        "temp":291.07,
        "temp_min":290.77,
        "temp_max":291.07,
        "pressure":1020.65,
        "sea_level":1027.03,
        "grnd_level":1020.65,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0.3
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":1.31,
        "deg":225.5
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 09:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534248000,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.286,
        "temp_min":293.286,
        "temp_max":293.286,
        "pressure":1020.78,
        "sea_level":1027.17,
        "grnd_level":1020.78,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"02d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":8
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.83,
        "deg":234.501
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 12:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534258800,
     "main":{
        "temp":298.671,
        "temp_min":298.671,
        "temp_max":298.671,
        "pressure":1020.76,
        "sea_level":1027.15,
        "grnd_level":1020.76,
        "humidity":92,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.71,
        "deg":259.5
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 15:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534269600,
     "main":{
        "temp":300.7,
        "temp_min":300.7,
        "temp_max":300.7,
        "pressure":1019.76,
        "sea_level":1026.18,
        "grnd_level":1019.76,
        "humidity":83,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":24
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.66,
        "deg":285.503
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":1.11
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 18:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534280400,
     "main":{
        "temp":298.464,
        "temp_min":298.464,
        "temp_max":298.464,
        "pressure":1019.68,
        "sea_level":1025.97,
        "grnd_level":1019.68,
        "humidity":83,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10d"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":48
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.27,
        "deg":289.504
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":1.61
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"d"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-14 21:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534291200,
     "main":{
        "temp":297.882,
        "temp_min":297.882,
        "temp_max":297.882,
        "pressure":1020,
        "sea_level":1026.37,
        "grnd_level":1020,
        "humidity":82,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":500,
           "main":"Rain",
           "description":"light rain",
           "icon":"10n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":36
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.37,
        "deg":275.004
     },
     "rain":{
        "3h":0.13
     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 00:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534302000,
     "main":{
        "temp":295.242,
        "temp_min":295.242,
        "temp_max":295.242,
        "pressure":1021.11,
        "sea_level":1027.53,
        "grnd_level":1021.11,
        "humidity":94,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":802,
           "main":"Clouds",
           "description":"scattered clouds",
           "icon":"03n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":32
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":1.26,
        "deg":313.002
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 03:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534312800,
     "main":{
        "temp":294.05,
        "temp_min":294.05,
        "temp_max":294.05,
        "pressure":1021.27,
        "sea_level":1027.77,
        "grnd_level":1021.27,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":2.46,
        "deg":274.504
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 06:00:00"
  },
  {
     "dt":1534323600,
     "main":{
        "temp":293.495,
        "temp_min":293.495,
        "temp_max":293.495,
        "pressure":1021.36,
        "sea_level":1027.7,
        "grnd_level":1021.36,
        "humidity":100,
        "temp_kf":0
     },
     "weather":[
        {
           "id":800,
           "main":"Clear",
           "description":"clear sky",
           "icon":"01n"
        }
     ],
     "clouds":{
        "all":0
     },
     "wind":{
        "speed":3.01,
        "deg":277.505
     },
     "rain":{

     },
     "sys":{
        "pod":"n"
     },
     "dt_txt":"2018-08-15 09:00:00"
],
"city":{
  "id":4347778,
  "name":"Baltimore",
  "coord":{
     "lat":39.2909,
     "lon":-76.6108
  },
  "country":"US",
  "population":620961
```

}
}

Comment: show me your `Main` class.

Comment: And can you show me what you've got from server? (raw string data)

Comment: I added the main class and raw data. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the "list" object first.

Either parse the list into a Json Object first Or do "ForecastWeatherListWrapper"

```
public class ForecastWeatherListWrapper {

   @SerializedName("list")
   @Expose
   private List<ForecastWeatherList> forecastWeatherLists;

   public List<ForecastWeatherList> getforecastWeatherLists() {
        return forecastWeatherLists;
    }

    public void setforecastWeatherLists(List<ForecastWeatherList> forecastWeatherItems){

       this.forecastWeatherLists = forecastWeatherItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm not clear how I can do this. I would do JSON first and then GSON? I would something like this first: JSONArray list=json.getJSONArray("list"); then go into GSON?

Comment: Well thats one way to do it. Or just edit your "ForecastWeatherListWrapper" with the SerializedName as what i mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `raw data` has more data than the API doc from https://openweathermap.org/forecast5. (eg. `rain`)

If you can get all data you want, It seems that there is no problem.

In my opinion, https://openweathermap.org/ didn't documented all responses.

Comment: Are you saying my connection to the internet is ok or my code? Its not clear. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Oh, please follow answer of @Archie G. Quiñones. Add `@SerializedName("list") ` to your forecastWeatherLists.